# What is the German word for a "SQL lookup table"?

Tags: word-choice, technical-terminology

What would the best German word be for an SQL table whose only purpose is to match e.g. an id with a name? In English, I would call this a "lookup table" since the ID is "looked up" and the corresponding name is returned.

My best guess would be **Nachschlagtabelle**?
Is that the standard term?

[image]

Comment: What is the difference to just a `table`? Don't you use all tables to lookup something?

Comment: Man müsste einen der deutschsprachigen SQL-Instruktoren, der ohne rot zu werden von 'Sichten' statt von 'Views' fragen. Wie man die erreicht kann ich leider nicht sagen, aber ich gehe davon aus, das diese um stimmige Übersetzungen bemüht sind.

Comment: I just asked on http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/462/are-questions-about-translations-of-database-termini-to-other-languages-tolerate, if the question would be acceptable there. I think the answer must be given by those with teaching practice in that field.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wikipedia says

> *[Lookup-Tabelle](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup-Tabelle)*,

translating only half the word. That is not uncommon in IT language, where English is the de-facto standard.

If you want/need an all-German term, I would propose either

> [*Nachschlag***e***tabelle*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms171924%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (a *Nachschlag* is a 2nd serving of food after you've finished the previous)

or

> *[Wertetabelle](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wertetabelle)*.

Strictly speaking, the latter is a mathematical term, but the same idea and maybe close enough, depending on the circumstances, as usual.

Comment: +1 für Lookup-Tabelle

Comment: I'm not too happy with "Wertetabelle", because the term lookup-table has a strong emphasis on the function of the described table.
However, Lookup-Tabelle is fine.

Comment: +1 for suggesting that a *Nachschlagtabelle* would relate to food.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the [nice suggestions already made](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/what-is-the-german-word-for-a-sql-lookup-table/2784#2784) we could also use

> [tabellarisches] Verzeichnis

where in *Verzeichnis* the purpose to look up something is inherent.

A composite noun translated from *look-up* and *table* is not generally used but possible. Analogous to *"Nachschlagewerk"* it would have to be built like this

> Nachschlagetabelle

Answer (score 3):

I agree, **die Nachschlagetabelle** seems to be a well-established term. Here are some translation examples:
http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/nachschlagetabelle.html

Comment: Linguee results may be biased as only translated texts are displayed (that not necessarily are translated well). Doing a Google search reveals that *"look-up tabelle"* has twice the number of hits as compared to *"Nachlagetabelle"* but still *"Wertetabelle*" is found 10 times more often. Of course Google hits are not scientific either ;)

Comment: @Takkat: *Wertetabelle* appears frequently because it is commonly used in basic maths education to speak of [the particular table that contains the *values* of a function](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wertetabelle) (as opposed to, for instance, different functions, parameters, ...). Other than with that background information, it is rather a pretty pointless term, and I doubt its general use in IT. After all, what else could a table in a database possibly contain beside "values", which, in IT, has a much broader meaning than in the aforementioned functional analysis context?

Answer (score 2):

I do a lot of work within SQL server, and apart from Lookup-Tabelle as Hackworth suggested, we often use **Referenztabelle** for something like this. After all, you (should) have referential integrity in place, so you have a reference from a column in another table referring to the primary key column within this table. And for those types of tables, *looking up* things based on the keys is one of the main uses.